# Как грамотно переписать css стили фреймворка?

Tags: css, less, uikit

Доброе утро! Начал изучать uikit и сразу же возник вопрос: как грамотно переписать css стили фреймворка под свои нужды?

Вот есть у меня uikit.less, в котором подключены все остальные less файлы фреймворка:

```
// LESS related
@import "core/variables.less";

// Defaults
@import "core/base.less";

// Layout
@import "core/grid.less";
@import "core/panel.less";
@import "core/block.less";
@import "core/article.less";
@import "core/comment.less";
@import "core/cover.less";

// Navs
@import "core/nav.less";
@import "core/navbar.less";
@import "core/subnav.less";
@import "core/breadcrumb.less";
@import "core/pagination.less";
@import "core/tab.less";
@import "core/thumbnav.less";

// Elements
@import "core/list.less";
@import "core/description-list.less";
@import "core/table.less";
@import "core/form.less";

// Common
@import "core/button.less";
@import "core/icon.less";
@import "core/close.less";
@import "core/badge.less";
@import "core/alert.less";
@import "core/thumbnail.less";
@import "core/overlay.less";
@import "core/column.less";
@import "core/animation.less";

// JavaScript
@import "core/dropdown.less";
@import "core/modal.less";
@import "core/offcanvas.less";
@import "core/switcher.less";

// Need to be loaded last
@import "core/text.less";
@import "core/utility.less";
@import "core/flex.less";
@import "core/contrast.less";
@import "core/print.less";
```

После чего используя winless я компилирую uikit.less в папку с css стилями и подключаю в основном css файле:

```
/*   
Theme Name:
Version:
Author:
*/

@import "css/uikit.css";
```

Собственно по uikit информации на русском мало, но читал на тостере по поводу bootstrap и там пишут что трогать само ядро фреймворка не желательно. Получается что редактировать компоненты нельзя? А если писать в основной css файл стили по верх стилей фремворка, то получается дублирование кода.

Как вы верстаете используя фреймворк, что посоветуете в моем случае? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не обязательно использовать данный фреймворк, то лучше написать свои стили с нуля, и сразу логически разбивать их на отдельные .css файлы, и самому удобнее будет, и читабельность повысится, и отлаживать проще если что.
Копаться в костях фреймворка и пытаться изменить .css в уже готовом решении можно, но рискуете очень сильно всё поломать. Возможно, имеет смысл взять какие-то части из фреймворка и создать отдельно свои стили, если не хотите таскать весь фрейм.

Comment: Просто охота как то ускорить процесс верстки.

Answer (score 0):

Лично я пользуюсь [**UIKit customizer**](http://getuikit.com/docs/customizer.html)